# Limit prefetch in Publisher

Tags: java, performance, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I want to create a `Flux` which have elements generated on-demand with a limited prefetch.

I have tried the following thing, but it look likes this code does not handle back-pressure, since `generateElements` becomes really big (1011):

```java
AtomicInteger generateElements = new AtomicInteger(0);
Flux<Integer> source = Flux
    .create(emitter -> {
        while (true)
            emitter.next(generateElements.getAndIncrement());
        })
    .subsribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .limitRate(1);

source.take(4).subsribe(System.out::println);
assertThat(generateElements.get()).isEqualTo(5);
```

How can I make my `Flux` limited to only one prefetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Flux.generate`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.function.Consumer-) which expects a callable where you define a single item emission:

```java
AtomicInteger generateElements = new AtomicInteger(0);

Flux.generate(emitter -> emitter.next(generateElements.getAndIncrement()))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .take(4)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```